# リクエストイがJSONに送りたいですが、どうすればいいでしょうか。

Tags: java

以下のリクエストイメージがJSONに条件として送りたいですが、JSONへの変換にどのようなライブラリを使用されているのかをお知らせください。`List<NameValuePai>`が使えますか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
{
    "a":{
        "b":"xxx",
        "c":"xxxxx"
    },
    "d":{
        "e":"xxx",
        "f":"xxxxx"
    }
}
```

Comment: 「以下のデータ」は既に(ほぼ)正しいJSON形式になっているので、「以下のデータがJSONにポストしたい」と言うのが何をやりたいのか、完全に理解できていないのですが、「示された形式のJSONに変換できるようなJavaのデータ(とデータ型)を定義したい」と言うことでよろしいでしょうか？だとしたら、JSONへの変換にどのようなライブラリを使用されているのかをお知らせください。

Comment: #OOPerさん、修正を頂きましてありがとうございます。
了解です。修正いたします。